# Some files in Eclipse are greyed out / no syntax coloring / functions aren't recognized

Tags: eclipse, macos, ide, eclipse-cdt

So I'm not sure if it has to do with the version of the eclipse that I'm using but some files are totally greyed out (no syntax coloring) and can't even get to the definition of a certain variable/function by hovering over it while pressing CMD key (mac), which is super annoying.

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it always the same kind of file? Are you opening them in the right editor? With Eclipse being a platform for tools, do you actually have the tools for the language you're working with installed?

Comment: I don't know how to tell if it's the same kind of file but they're the source files as well. I see no issues with files like `main.c`, and a few others .

Comment: Sources in what language? Every language could need its own set of plug-ins.

Comment: I meant `.c` source file

Comment: At a minimum, you might want to show views wider than what you've shown here, including the tab in the code panel, and the package/project explorer, showing the project and folders of the project.

Comment: does this help? @DavidM.Karr

Comment: also realised when clicking into the function calls from `task.h` in `main.c` takes me to `task.h` and not `task.c` where it's defined as it is with other functions where I don't see this greying out issue

Comment: ...I guess not?